# VR gaze system from scratch, pointer didnt follow mobile "head"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I started to make a simple VR gaze system from scratch, using Unity ARFoundation. First thing was to draw a line from my point of view to "infinity", like a pointer. I have this script running on my AR Session Origin at Update:

```
    myLine.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
    myLine.SetPosition(1, transform.position+(transform.forward*1000));
```

This works on editor, I have a line, and I can turn and move my session origin (my "head" with camera), it follows up.

But, when I use it on mobile... the line keeps still, doesnt turn and move with the device.

What´s wrong?

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? How is this GameObject supposed to be moved when the devices moves? Also ... wouldn't this simply result in a point for the VR camera (or even nothing at all)? The "line" is supposed to be aligned with our view direction so you probably won't see anything ...

Comment: Did you consider to simply attach a Cursor/Line object to the camera as child so it is always moved and rotated along with it without even needing a script for it?

Comment: Hello, @derHugo. Yes, I attached a child object, same thing, move along in editor, does not work on device.

About the code, theres not much beyond that for the case, this "myLine" its a Unity LineRenderer, that works well for other things (including on device), and I have the pattern for ARFoundation working (AR Session, AR Session Origin..., I already have another VR scene working, this one its for this gazing system alone)

Comment: Don't add "solved" or similar verbiage to the title.  Instead, you can mark your answer as accepted after a time limit has elapsed.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved

Comment: Oops, sorry. But "You can accept your own answer in two days" ... in two days I don't even know if I'm going to be working on this project, especially remembering to come back here and mark an answer as resolved ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well... nevermind. I solve it. I needed a reference to the arCameraManager, it holds the head-tracking information.

```
myLine.SetPosition(0, arCameraManager.transform.position);
myLine.SetPosition(1, arCameraManager.transform.position+arCameraManager.transform.forward*100));
```

o/